# Client network socket disconnected before secure TLS connection was established aws lambda nodejs

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda

--> I have a basic set up of lambda function with eventBridge.this function is invoked after every 2 minute. There I have tournaments.txt file which has 35 tournaments ID and for each tournament ID I am fetching data from an api.
--> Then I am saving those fetched data to database using another serverless routes.
Now in the cloudwatch log, my lambda function is giving error attached as screenshot below
[image]

my lambda function code

```
const axios = require("axios");
const fs = require("fs");

const writeResult = async (id) => {
  console.log(id);
  try {
    const res = await axios.get(`${BASE_URL}/${id}.xml?json=1`);
    if (res) {
    const matches = res?.data?.commentaries?.tournament?.match;
      if (Array.isArray(matches)) {
        await Promise.all(
          matches.map(async (m) => {
            try {
              await axios.post(
                "https:example.com//route1",
                m
              );
              await axios.post(
                "https:example.com//route2",
                m
              );
              await axios.post(
                "https:example.com//route3",
                m
              );
              await axios.post(
                "https:example.com//route4",
                m
              );
              await axios.post(
                "https:example.com//route5",
                m
              );
              await axios.post(
                "https:example.com//route6",
                m
              );
            } catch (error) {
              console.log(error.message);
            }
          })
        );
      } 
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error.message);
  }
};
exports.handler = async () => {
  const ids = fs
    .readFileSync("tournaments.txt", "utf-8")
    .replace(/\r/g, "")
    .trim()
    .split("\n");

  Promise.all(
    ids.map((id) => {
      writeResult(id);
    })
  );
  
  return "finally done";
};
```

What is the probable issue here? I've done some research but did not find any helpful solution.

Answer (score 2):

I've solved the issue. just added **await** before Promise.all() and now everything is working fine